# SSL certificate problem

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

i have a vps with cpanel and whm, i've purchased an SSL certificate and i installed it successfully on a second ip address, but when i visit https://www.domain.com it doesn't work, because my domain name only goes to the first ip, so currently it's served from one ip, How to make it served from the second ip when accessing the https method?

Note: i'm new at this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the DNS for www.domain.com to point to your second IP address. Be aware that doing so will cause http://www.domain.com to also answer on that IP address.

I don't fully follow the description of your problem. Unless you're hosting more than one SSL domain you probably don't really need the second IP address.

Comment: Thanks, u r right, i don't really need a second ip